# In App Purchase Problem

Tags: iphone

please help me , i am getting product count 0 in response.product.
i have followed all the steps of in app purchase in documentation .
1.Provisioning profile and i allowed in app purchase.
2.Dummy app binary uploaded to itunes and rejected that by myself.
3.Setup 2 products in itunes in app purchase and app identifier was selected.

All the things seems fine but i am getting product count 0.

Please let me know how can i solve this issue .

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to check the "Cleared for Sale" checkbox for the in-app purchase in iTunes Connect.  Note that this does not submit the in-app purchase for approval to Apple.  To do that, you need to click the green "Approve" button in the upper right hand corner.

All you should need to do to *test* the in-App purchase is check the "Cleared for Sale" checkbox for the purchase in iTunes Connect.

Comment: yes , my purchase item is cleared for sale and also i have a "waiting for review" status there ..

Answer (score 1):

Don't reject your binary. The binary has to be waiting for review (or cleared for sale) before the store will work right.

Also make sure each of your in app purchase items are cleared for sale on iTunes Connect.

Comment: thanks for reply , my application is not completed yet , if i leave it in a review , it will be rejected . so that's why i rejected by myself and also i read somewhere to reject it . also my purchase items are cleared for sale and status of items is "Waiting for review".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new application but not upload the binary on iTunes Connect. This way your app is in the "Waiting for binary" (or something like that) state.

Then you're binary won't be rejected.

If anybody needs help implementing the In App Purchase feature, there's a complete sample [here](http://www.theapptree.com/samples)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure add Product information in iTunes conect.

Enter iTunes Connect, Click Manage Your In app Purchases link, add Product information and id.

I post a summary in my msn space http://leefj.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!ADF54DD0A549AD9B!471.entry
 [image]

Comment: yes , i have submited application information and item is cleared for sale . 
what should i try now ?